# How to do the following graph in LaTeX with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

is there anybody who can help me with graph in graph pictures? [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Hi Tomas, welcome to the site! Could you add some more information on what you're trying to achieve and what your boundary conditions are? Are you struggling with creating a basic plot (like the scatter plot and the parabolas), or do you want to know how to create the inset plots? What have you tried so far? What questions have you found on this site or on Texample.com that could get you started?

Answer (score 6):

This should give you a starting point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  inset/.style args={#1,(#2,#3)}{
    width=4cm,height=3cm,
    at=(mainplot.center),
    name=#1,
    shift={(#2,#3)},
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[name=mainplot,
    ymajorgrids,xmin=0,xmax=800,ymin=0,ymax=40,
    width=\linewidth]
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
      (0,36) (100,27) (200,14) (300,13) (400,11) (500,15) (600,24) (700,17)
    };
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
      (0,19) (100,22) (200,16) (300,16) (400,26)
    };
    \addplot+[no marks,blue,domain=0:700] {(35-12)/400^2*(x-400)^2+12};
    \addplot+[no marks,red,domain=0:400]  {(21-17)/170^2*(x-170)^2+17};
    \node (ref-i1) at (axis cs:0,36)   {};
    \node (ref-i2) at (axis cs:400,26) {};
    \node (ref-i3) at (axis cs:300,13) {};
    \node (ref-i4) at (axis cs:500,15) {};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[inset={i1,(-4.2cm,2.7cm)}]
    \addplot+[blue,no marks,samples=200] {rnd};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[inset={i2,(.5cm,1.5cm)}]
    \addplot+[red,no marks,samples=200] {rnd};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[inset={i3,(-3.2cm,-3.5cm)}]
    \addplot+[blue,no marks,samples=200] {rnd};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[inset={i4,(2cm,-3cm)}]
    \addplot+[blue,no marks,samples=200] {rnd};
  \end{axis}
  \draw[blue,->] (i1) -- (ref-i1);
  \draw[red, ->] (i2) -- (ref-i2);
  \draw[blue,->] (i3) -- (ref-i3);
  \draw[blue,->] (i4) -- (ref-i4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]